# Let $\gamma=\{z\in \Bbb C: \lvert z \rvert=2\}$ in anti-clockwise orientation. Then $I=\frac {1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma} z^7 \cos \frac 1{z^2} dz$=?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

> $$I=\frac {1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma} z^7 \cos \frac 1{z^2} dz=?$$

The function $\cos \frac 1{z^2}$ is neither analytic at $z=0$ and nor it has a pole at $z=0$. By Cauchy Integral Formula can I get the right answer? Or there is some other method?

Since $\cos \frac 1{z^2}$ does not have pole at $z=0$, can I say that the integral is zero by Cauchy Integral Theorem?

Comment: Please put the integral in the main body of the question - it will be more readable. Also perhaps with the $\frac{1}{2 \pi i}$ before the integral, again for readability.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Okay.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Is it okay now?

Comment: Looks good. I have made a minor fix in the title, \lvert and \rvert.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Great! :)

Comment: Yes, $\cos \frac{1}{z^2}$ doesn't have a pole at $z=0$, it has an essential singularity, since all the powers of the Laurent's expansion are negative. I'd suggest going with a substitution $s=\frac{1}{z^2}$ to make the integral easier to evaluate.

Comment: @A.Jiménez Okay thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint : Do the change $w = \frac{1}{z}.$

You get $$\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{\gamma} z^7 \cos \frac 1{z^2} dz = -\frac{1}{2i\pi} \int_{\gamma'} \frac{cos(w^2)}{w^9}dw,$$ where $\gamma' = \{z : |z| = 1/2\}.$

Now Cauchy Integral formula can help you.

Comment: Can we do substitution in complex integration like that? I didn't know about it.

Comment: If you're not convinced, you can go back to a parametrization and do the substitution at this level.

Comment: It's not that I'm not convinced. In fact this is really amazing method new for me. :) $\\$ Just a  little correction in your answer: The power of $\omega$ in the denominator should be $7$. You have written it to be $9$ mistakenly.

Comment: Don't forget the jacobian. :)

Comment: I am doomed!! :D

Answer (score 2):

You can just extract the coefficient of the $\frac1z$-term of the series expansion of the integrand. Specifically, 
$$
z^7\cos(1/z^2) =z^7\left(1 - \frac{z^{-4}}{2} + \frac{z^{-8}}{24} - \cdots\right) = z^7 - \frac{z^3}{2} + \frac{z^{-1}}{24} - \cdots
$$
which means that we have
$$
I = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma z^7\cos\frac{1}{z^2} dz =\frac1{2\pi i}\int_\gamma \frac{1}{24}\cdot \frac{1}{z}dz = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\cdot\frac{2\pi i}{24}= \frac{1}{24}$$

Comment: By going with the method of @C.Dubussy we can say that $I=\frac 1{6!} \frac {d\cos \omega^2}{d\omega}|_{\omega=0}=\frac 0{6!}=0$ because https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sixth+derivative+of+cos(x%5E2) . $\\$ Where did I went wrong then?

Comment: Also why should we extract coefficient of $\frac 1z$ only?

Comment: @VikrantDesai Because $\int_\gamma z^n\,dz = 0$ for any $n \in \Bbb Z \setminus \{-1\}$, so the contribution to the total integral from any other term of the series expansion is $0$.

Comment: But I got $I=0$ by the method of previous answerer.

Comment: Why does $\int_{\gamma} z^n dz=0$ for any $n \in \Bbb Z$ \ $\{-1\}$? I can understand it for $n \in \Bbb Z^+$.

Comment: @VikrantDesai You can, for instance, read [this PDF](http://www.math.columbia.edu/~rf/complex3.pdf), where the result that $\int_\gamma z^n\,dz=0$ for $n\neq-1$ appears on the top of page $8$. In some sense it comes from the fact that $\frac1z$ doesn't have a continuous antiderivative, but they calculate it explicitly in the case of $n=-2$ as well to illustrate the point.

Comment: I am extremely sorry. I calculated $I$ again and it turns out to be $\frac {1}{24}$. Also thanks for giving a different and simple approach.